# While using PDB files with source server info in them, how do I open arbitrary source code files while debugging in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, source-server

In my project I successfully generated PDB files with SVN repository information in them. While debugging a process I can click on any stack frame in the call stack window and it successfully fetches the corresponding source file from SVN and opens it. So far so good!

Now the problem is that this only works if I try to open a source file by clicking on a stack frame in the call stack window. This means that I can only fetch source files that have code that is currently being used by a thread. What if I want to open an include file? Or set a breakpoint in some other code file?

I've tried right-clicking an `#include "HEADER_FILE.h"` and clicking `Open Document "HEADER_FILE.h"`, but Visual Studio tries to open the file on disk (which doesn't exist) instead of fetching it from SVN, and obviously fails to open it.

I want to be able to open any source file, how can I get Visual Studio to automatically fetch it from SVN?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Thank you!